# Taking ownership of trustedinstaller files?

Tags: windows-vista, ntfs, security

vista32-sp1: I am unable to delete some files on my system that were installed with 'special permissions' by 'trustedinstaller'. I find the usual help suggestion to use 'takeown' is not working, all I get is access denied. I refuse to believe there isn't some way to delete these files, or that microsoft has finally acheived their perfect security filesystem.

This is NOT a case of a file being locked by a process. If this is all it was, I could solve this by myself. I know there are some recommended unlocking programs and they might do some sort of file system trick, but I would like to know what my possible direct actions might be. If a 3rd party program can 'unlock' a file, I want to know the mechanism. But like I said 'takeown' at the command line is not working for this.

Answer (score 0):

> microsoft has finally acheived their
>   perfect security filesystem.

certainly not, you can always delete files that are locked/protected by the system with the help of a Linux Live Distro (Linux doesn't give a hoot about Windows Permissions, ya know :).

note: do this at your own risk, there is that possibility that you will break the OS.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think of that.. Is the NTFS support in linux mature enough to be trusted now? I haven't used it in a couple of years.

Comment: but of course, Knoppix for instance, is a great distro for 'fiddling' with Windows systems externally. http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html